# Microsoft Bookings availability is not correct

Tags: microsoft

I'm experiencing this problem where Microsoft Bookings' availability bears no relation to the default work hours and location that I have set up in Calendar.

I made a 2 minute video that demonstrates the problem here: https://vimeo.com/850402150/3c22f401ed

Anyone got any ideas? I'd be grateful.

regards,
Ben

Comment: It is not SharePoint related question

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Raf. Still trying to navigate the MS ecosystem and understand what goes where...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug. Gave it a test and it seems to honour selected days ok, but for the available times, it took the earliest and latest time across all days, and applied that to each available day. Granular times set from Outlook appear to be ignored.

[image]

Using the custom availability hours works a lot better though.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Paul. The custom availability hours had the same bug for me. Pretty weird, is nobody using Bookings? I

Comment: Good question! ;-)